# Multiple Views in accessoryView of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am trying to overlay two images in the `accessoryView` of a `UITableViewCell` like so:

```
UIView *accessoryView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.accessoryView.frame];

UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CellBG.png"]];
UIImageView *tickImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tick.png"]];

[accessoryView addSubview:backgroundImage];
[accessoryView addSubview:tickImage];

cell.accessoryView = accessoryView;

// release stuff
```

Sadly, this doesn't work and the two images are lying in strange places on the screen...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The frames of the images need to be set to the bounds of the accessory view. You might also want to try setting the accessory view frame manually. Eg.
    CGRectMake(0,0,20,20)

Comment: Setting the bounds didn't change anything, but creating the frame manually worked! Strange...

Comment: It's because by getting the frame from cell.accessoryView you actually get the frame set by the cellView or random muck.  It won't have an origin of 0, 0. However, when you set something as an accessory view uicellview autocomputes the origin and adds it to yours. Thus for it to work properly an origin of 0, 0 was required :)

Comment: you could either use the CGRectMake that he shows above or you could make a new nib custom table cell with the pictures in them.